# Need guidance with java coding

Tags: java

Hi eveyone it's first time here.

I have an assignment where I need to write code for a payment card, and I'm completely lost. The card should do the following :

- check activation
- Have minimal balance (5)
- Have maximal balance (125)
- Add money
- Withdraw money (pay)

When you add an amount that doesn't follow the minimal or maximal balance, it should print out a line of text, saying "value should be at least 5" or "the maximum balance is 125". It works fine for the minimal line, but when you try adding more than 125 it prints out the line and still adds the amount.

Here's all my code:

```
public class protonkaart
```

{

```
private double balans;
private boolean activate;
private int min;
private int max;

public protonkaart()
{

    balans = 0;
    activate = false;
    min = 5;
    max = 125;
}

public double getBalans()

{
   return balans;

}
/**
 * balansOpladen = Add money to balance 
 */
public void balansOpladen (double bedrag)
{
    if ((bedrag >= 5) && (balans <= 125))
    {
        balans += bedrag;
    }
    if ((bedrag <= 5))
    { 
        System.out.println("U moet minstens 5 euro opladen.");
    } 
    if ((bedrag >=125))
    {
        balans += 0;
        System.out.println("U mag maximaal 125 euro opladen!");
    }
}
```

}

Any help is welcome.

Comment: This isn't a homework writing service. You need to be specific about what the actual issue is with your code - including error messages you are receiving. If there are no issues with your code, and you simply don't know where to begin you would be best asking your instructor.

Comment: Your first check is incomplete. think of what happens if you try to add, say, a million but the balance is under 125. None of your code prevents that from happening.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have to check if the **sum** is less then 125 and not the current value.

```
public void balansOpladen (double bedrag) {
    if ((bedrag + balans >= 5) && (balans + balans <= 125)) {
        balans += bedrag;
    }
    if ((bedrag + balans <= 5)) { 
        System.out.println("U moet minstens 5 euro opladen.");
    } 
    if ((bedrag + balans >=125)) {
        System.out.println("U mag maximaal 125 euro opladen!");
    }
}
```

Also I would make some changes to how this method is structured as follow:

```
public void balansOpladen (double bedrag) {
    if (bedrag + balans <= 5) { 
        System.out.println("U moet minstens 5 euro opladen.");
    } else if (bedrag + balans >=125) {
        System.out.println("U mag maximaal 125 euro opladen!");
    } else {
        balans += bedrag;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Aleb!